# TableViewController to 2nd level ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview

I have a very specific problem. I am very new to Xcode, but so far I was able to make an app with tab bar controller, where 1 of the tab controllers is tableviewcontroller. I have no problem displaying table cells in tableviewcontroller and even clicking anyone of them segueing to detailviewcontroller where table cells have extensive info, but my problem is when I am trying to segue my way even further, by clicking menu button, where I want a label and an image of a menu to show. I am getting a blank screen. I can't even see a title, not even talking about pushing through an image.
I assume problem is with pushing through the info through a level.
Here is TableViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TableViewController1 : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Menus;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Images;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Description;

@end
```

And TableViewController.m:

```
#import "TableViewController1.h"
#import "TableCell1.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"
@interface TableViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController1

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:181/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:0.5];
    UIBarButtonItem *NewBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:NewBackButton];

    _Title = @[@"Velvet Sport Villa",
               @"GQ",
               @"29",
               @"Noodles",
               @"La Roof",
               @"Borgo Antico",
               @"Vertalet",
               @"Balcon",
               @"Parmigiano",];
    _Description = @[@"The New Great Place",
               @"Want to feel some luxury",
               @"The Old Good Place",
               @"Food is amazing here",
               @"Too expensive",
               @"Royal place",
               @"Before party or After party",
               @"Great place, great deserts",
               @"The first place in town of that level",];
    _Images = @[@"Velvet.jpg",
                @"GQ.jpg",
                @"29.jpg",
                @"Noodles.jpg",
                @"La Roof.jpg",
                @"Borgo Antico.jpg",
                @"Vertalet.jpg",
                @"Balcon.jpg",
                @"Parmigiano.jpg",];
    _Menus = @[@"Velvet Menu.jpg",
               @"GQ Menu.jpg",
               @"29 Menu.jpg",
               @"Noodles Menu.jpg",
               @"La Roof Menu.jpg",
               @"Borgo Antico Menu.jpg",
               @"Vertalet Menu.jpg",
               @"Balcon Menu.jpg",
               @"Parmigiano Menu.jpg",];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _Title.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell1";
    TableCell1 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    int row = [indexPath row];

    cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
    cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _Description[row];
    cell.ThumbImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_Images[row]];

    return cell;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"])
    {
        DetailViewController *detailviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *myInderPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        int row = [myInderPath row];
        detailviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row],_Description[row],_Images[row],_Menus[row]];
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MenuDetails"])
    {
        MenuViewController *menuviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *myInderPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        int row = [myInderPath row];
        menuviewcontroller.MenuModal = @[_Title[row],_Menus[row]];
    }

}
@end
```

TableCell1.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableCell1 : UITableViewCell

@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DescriptionLabel;
@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ThumbImage;

@end
```

TableCell1.m

```
#import "TableCell1.h"

@implementation TableCell1

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
// Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Cuisine;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Price;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Decor;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Service;


@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DescriptionLabel;
@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ThumbImage;

@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray *DetailModal;

@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _TitleLabel.text = _DetailModal[0];
    _DescriptionLabel.text = _DetailModal[1];
    _ThumbImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_DetailModal[2]];

    self.navigationItem.title = _DetailModal[0];

    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Velvet Sport Villa"])
    {
        _Cuisine.text = @"German/American";
        _Price.text = @"Above average";
        _Decor.text = @"Great. Sporty, but cozy";
        _Service.text = @"Exceptional";
    }
    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"GQ"])
    {
        _Cuisine.text = @"Italian/English";
        _Price.text = @"Above average";
        _Decor.text = @"Exceptional";
        _Service.text = @"Average";
    }

    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"29"])
    {
        _Cuisine.text = @"Japanese/Italian";
        _Price.text = @"Average";
        _Decor.text = @"Cozy";
        _Service.text = @"So So";
    }
    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Noodles"])
    {
        _Cuisine.text = @"Chinese/Italian";
        _Price.text = @"Average";
        _Decor.text = @"Interesting";
        _Service.text = @"Groomy, but fast";
    }
    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"La Roof"])
    {
        _Cuisine.text = @"American/Italian";
        _Price.text = @"Very High";
        _Decor.text = @"OK";
        _Service.text = @"OK";
    }
    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Borgo Antico"])
    {
        _Cuisine.text = @"Medeterranean";
        _Price.text = @"Above average";
        _Decor.text = @"Marvelous";
        _Service.text = @"Not Bad";
    }
    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Vertalet"])
    {
        _Cuisine.text = @"All";
        _Price.text = @"Above average";
        _Decor.text = @"Fine, nothing special";
        _Service.text = @"Not Bad";
    }
    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Balcon"])
    {
        _Cuisine.text = @"Italian/Coffee";
        _Price.text = @"Above Average";
        _Decor.text = @"Modern";
        _Service.text = @"Best";
    }
    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Parmigiano"])
    {
        _Cuisine.text = @"Italian";
        _Price.text = @"Above Average";
        _Decor.text = @"Stunning";
        _Service.text = @"Annoying";
    }

}
@end
```

Finally MenuViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *MenuImage;

@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray *MenuModal;
@end
```

And Lastly MenuViewController.m

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController ()

@end

@implementation MenuViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = _MenuModal[0];
    _TitleLabel.text = _MenuModal[0];
    _MenuImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_MenuModal[3]];
}
@end
```